# How can I tell which package is using old AsyncStorage version

Tags: react-native, expo, node-modules, asyncstorage

I updated all of my dependencies in my expo managed project for react native. Everything so far  appears to be working but now I'm getting a warning that says:

```
AsyncStorage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage
```

In all of the files I've written I call for AsyncStorage like this:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
```

So I'm left assuming that the deprecated use of:

```
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
```

must be coming from another node package / dependency that I'm using.....
What is the best way to check my project files to see what is generating this error?

I know it sounds like a stupid question, but in my IDE (vsCode) I have done a global search for "import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';" and I'm coming up with nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with this same issue, and I think I found a solution that works. In my `node_modules` folder there is a folder called `asyncstorage-down` that contains a file called `default-opts.js`. For me, the file originally contained the following:

```
module.exports = {
  get AsyncStorage() {
    return require('react-native').AsyncStorage
  }
}
```

I changed it to:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
export { AsyncStorage };
```

and was able to get rid of the error. There might be a better way to fix this, but this is what worked for me.

You may also need to run `pod install` in order to link `@react-native-async-storage/async-storage` to the Xcode project.

Note: this may be just something that I go through, but every time I manually run `pod install`, it causes the build to fail. I end up having to recreate my RN project and install all node modules before running `npx react-native-macos-init` (I am building a RN app for Mac-OS) so I would would recommend backing up your project before running `pod install` if needed